# IOS: a quickly way to set an image in a imageview

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

If I have an imageview of 77x77 and I want to adapt an UIImage in this imageview, is it possible?
at the example I want set in this imageview an image with a size of 300x200, is there a way to adapt this image inside this imageview (77x77) ??
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;`

The property is inherited from [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html).

UIViewContentMode

Specifies how a view adjusts its content when its size changes.

```
typedef enum {
   UIViewContentModeScaleToFill,
   UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit,
   UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill,
   UIViewContentModeRedraw,
   UIViewContentModeCenter,
   UIViewContentModeTop,
   UIViewContentModeBottom,
   UIViewContentModeLeft,
   UIViewContentModeRight,
   UIViewContentModeTopLeft,
   UIViewContentModeTopRight,
   UIViewContentModeBottomLeft,
   UIViewContentModeBottomRight,
} UIViewContentMode;
```